# GPU shows 0 utilization even when tensors and model are mounted on the gpu?

Tags: pytorch, gpu, nvidia

I am trying to run some PyTorch scripts on a remote GPU server. While calling the script in the ubuntu terminal i start as:`CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0(or whichever is available) python3 <script.py>`. Also, used the following snippet in the code and used .`to(device)` on the model, input and target tensors.

```
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
print(device)
```

I have confirmed that my model and data and target tensors are mounted on the cuda device. But the **GPU shows 0 percentage utilization** all through the run. What could I be missing?

Comment: How are you monitoring your GPU utilization? On windows, I tend to use [nvidia-smi](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-system-management-interface).

Comment: Yeah, same for ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to some modules I was importing without ensuring the tensors are mounted on cuda through that part of the pipeline. This had turned into the bottleneck blocking the GPU utilization.